# How reliable is data from CSI Market?

Tags: market-data, market

I am finishing up a reference guide for my graduate students on key financial ratios. Would like to include S&P 500 current metrics in my guide. But need to know how reliable is this company CSI Market.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have been searching for the same information as I noticed some of my students did use CSI market.  What bothered me is that there are no dates attached to the numbers.  The only number is the copyright year in small letters at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, there is no "About Us" tab, which would provide the opportunity to say something about the company, it staff, and other pertinent informations, that would lead one to assess the value of the company's product.

I was interested, as a response above noted, in using the data as a source for my managerial economics and forecasting class, but have no links for a contact person to discuss the matter.

Answer (score 0):

They are a provider for Yahoo Finance of "historical chart data and daily updates".

They are mentioned in the "Exchanges and data providers on Yahoo Finance" [page](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2310.html) under the "Data delays and providers" section.

> - Fundamental company data provided by Capital IQ. Historical chart data and daily updates provided by Commodity Systems, Inc. (CSI):

Answer (score 0):

CSImarket is Companies Sectors Industries Market, not Commodity Systems, Inc. as was suggested. And they do have an 'about us' section here: https://csimarket.com/help/About_us.php

I realize I'm posting 2 years later (things have updated) but I'm still interested in whether they're reliable.